# where could we see the list of npm and nodejs versions from first launched to the most updated one?

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there anyplace where we can find the exact versions from first to the latest one, I am trying to list the bugs they have solved and new functionality they have updated along path.

Comment: You can find all the nodejs versions at with links to docs also: https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Answer (score 0):

Check on their website, you will get what you require. Although you have to read the changelogs of every release they have ever had.
[This their previous releases website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/)